# Jquery form submission not working in chrome but working in firefox

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, firefox, paypal, wordpress

I have bit odd problem with same code working with firefox and not working in chrome.
My main functionality is I need to submit a form while clicking `buy now` button. On button click event I have written code for submitting form . My code is

```
$('.paypal_button_form_submit').click(function(){

              $('.form_certificate').submit();

               alert('Thank you! Your order was submitted successfully');               

});
```

By clicking on paypal it actually takes me to paypal but before that it submits the form.
Form I am using is

> caldera forms plugin

with wordpress.
with this code form works perfect in firefox but not in chrome.
Can you help me what changes I need to do to make it work in all browsers.

Comment: Need more context. Your DOM and maybe errors that you getting, because i pasted it into jsbin and it works fine on my chrome?

Comment: No syntax error in chrome. jUst this. GET http://***/wp-content/themes/theme/js/jquery.min.map 404 (Not Found)
Is this can be the problem?

Comment: Difficult to say, but it's possible

Comment: tried adding jquery.min.map at specified location, so now no error in dom. But still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved on my own. Just changed the click from paypal button to form submit button click.
So now my code is something like this.

```
$('#submit').on("click",function(){
     if($("#formid").valid())
    {
       $('.paypal_button_form').submit();
    }

});
```

I don't know why it worked but it worked. SO now both of the forms are getting submitted and functionality works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.on`

```
$('.paypal_button_form_submit').on("click",function(){

              $('.form_certificate').submit();

               alert('Thank you! Your order was submitted successfully');               

});
```

Comment: nothing selected, can't validate, returning nothing . Can this can get me in trouble?

Comment: u mean theres no validation on form .. how do you know if form is submitted .. what takes place in firefox if its working there.. and is alert occuring?

Comment: no there is validation in form. in firefox form submits, than alert message occurs and once I click Ok it takes me to paypal